# Exists with GetMetadata always returns true

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Using V2, I am trying to find out if a folder exists in an Azure blob storage (I am aware that 'folder' is a pseudo-name, since it is just part of a file url). When I attempt to do this, it always returns true, no matter if the folder exists or not.

Below is an example where it should return false, but returns true. The folderpath "test/2018/5/25" does not exist, but Get Metadata returns "exists: true, itemName: 25". Other folder paths exists, such as "test/2018/5/24, but not the one ending in 25, because there is no data for the 25th.

Any ideas?

Pipeline

```
{
"name": "Testing",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "Get Metadata1",
            "type": "GetMetadata",
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false
            },
            "typeProperties": {
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "metdatatest",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "fieldList": [
                    "itemName",
                    "exists"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Dataset

```
{
"name": "metdatatest",
"properties": {
    "linkedServiceName": {
        "referenceName": "xxx",
        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
    },
    "type": "AzureBlob",
    "typeProperties": {
        "format": {
            "type": "TextFormat",
            "columnDelimiter": "\t",
            "nullValue": "\\N",
            "treatEmptyAsNull": true,
            "skipLineCount": 1,
            "firstRowAsHeader": false
        },
        "fileName": "",
        "folderPath": "test/2018/5/25"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can repro the same, and this is a bug. It currently returns whether its container exists or not, but didn't check the existence of this "virtual" folder.

As blob doesn't have a folder concept, in order to know whether such a folder exists, it will need to do a file search to check if any file is under this folder, which could lead to a performance issue. I will circle back to the PROD team. Please stay tuned...

Comment: Ok, product team will fix this "exists" issue in a month. We identified another issue that LastModifiedTime on folder won't work. As a tradeoff between performance and feature, we decided to remove the support of LastModifiedTime for folder.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that follow-up. Sound like a reasonable tradeoff. How will I know if the fix has been pushed?

Comment: The fix is now sitting in the next deployment train. Should be propagated to all regions in a week or two.